# Forcing a disadvantage on an enemy's saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, advantage-and-disadvantage

Is it correct that the only on-demand ability that can instantaneously undercut a targeted creature's Saving Throw is Bend Luck? Or am I missing any?

- Cutting Words cannot be used on Saving Throws.
- Luck Points cannot be used on Saving Throws.
- Bane is gated by an initial Saving Throw (and like Bend Luck, only reduces 1 save by 1d4).
- Contagion *does* disadvantage Saves, but it is gated by several prior Saving Throws.

Is there any ability (like Luck Points) that I am missing that can be used to force a creature to roll a Saving Throw with disadvantage?

Comment: Please choose a question. Do you want to "instantaneously undercut a targeted creature's Saving Throw" or "force a creature to roll a Saving Throw with disadvantage?"

Comment: Specifically to force Disadvantage.

Comment: I am not sure of your phrasing but it may be of note that Bane reduces ANY and ALL saving throws by the afflicted creatures (up to 3 for 1st level) by 1d4, not just 1 save.  If a creature has to make 3 saves in a row on the same turn? Bane affects them all.

Comment: Are we to list any and every ability that gives saving throw disadvantages?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I was speaking to the broadness of the scope. It's not answerable in it's current state, other than to say "Yes, there are spells that do that" and no way to teach one how to easily search for that, as it's really just knowing the spells available.

Comment: Additional information from the OP is required. Is he comparing classes for a character, building an encounter for his party, or other?

Answer (score 11):

No, the Bend Luck feature is not the only method to undercut a creature's saving throw instantaneously.

### Wizard, School of Divination Portent Feature.

> After each long rest, roll two 2d20. Record the results. Then throughout the day, you can expend each result to make that be the outcome of any one attack roll, saving throw, or ability check for you or any creature you can see.

The outcome rolled by the diviner becomes the result of the targets roll. It is dependent on getting a low roll in the morning, but what isn't dependent?

Answer (score 9):

### Bestow Curse

As a 3rd level spell it is ok, though it also has an initial saving throw, just like Bane. However, as a 5th level spell it *does not require concentration*.

If the target fails the initial saving throw, it has disadvantage on saving throws linked to one ability score chosen by you.

Answer (score 9):

The sorcerer's metamagic 'Heightened Spell' forces a target creature making its first saving throw against the affected spell to do so with disadvantage, at the cost of three sorcery points.

Answer (score 8):

At level 10, the eldritch knight fighter archetype gets a feature called *eldritch strike*. From page 75 of the PHB:

> At 10th level, you learn how to make your weapon strikes undercut a creature's resistance to your spells. When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, that creature has disadvantage on the next saving throw it makes against a spell you cast before the end of your next turn.

The only pre-requisite for using this feature is hitting with a weapon attack, which is something the fighter in particular is very good at.