# Forcing a saving throw to be made with disadvantage

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, saving-throw, advantage-and-disadvantage

I know there is already a [similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79805/forcing-a-disadvantage-on-an-enemys-saving-throw), but it doesn't really give me an answer. Is there such a thing as a feat or an item that causes enemies to make saving throws like wisdom or general saving throws with disadvantage?

I wanted to create a mage (don't know which class yet) who specializes in CC and spells like Phantasmal Killer, but I don't feel like a high spellcasting mod would really be sufficient to make the CC more reliable.

edit: Based on comments and uncertainties, I would like to say that all ways to increase the likelihood that the spells will apply its effect are helpful. It doesn't have to be a disadvantage. It can also be an effect that increases my spell mod or decreases enemy saveroll as long as it can be used with a mageclass.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in feats and items? Does the effect have to be completely general (ie. any save)?

Comment: It doesnt need to be a feat or item but something that would provide a reliable way to give disadvantage on mainly wisdom  saving throws to make cc spells that cause paralysis or fear for example hit more reliable. I know there are several spells that give disadv. on saving throws but they need to hit too so that doesnt realy seem to help much.

Comment: So you're interested in a list of any and all ways to force a creature to have disadvantage on a given (Wisdom) Saving Throw, but only ones that do not require other spells?

Comment: If there is no better way, or it would be realy difficult to achieve that without a spell, i would take spells too but i prefer other ways than spells.

Comment: Why did you guys close my question? there is no reason to do so!

Comment: I voted to close because your edit made this incredibly broad. Asking for all things across everything that can increase the likelihood of a spell effect succeeding is too broad for us to answer.

Comment: Why though? There are many ideas on how to answer my question. Noone knows every way but if someone knows a good way he can just leave it here like they did before. Also my edit didnt change anything it just cleared up the confusion for the people who didnt understand the main text because they simply didnt read it right. Exept for the part where it says it does not have to be disadvantage.

Comment: Therefore i would like you to vote it beeing opened up again. I mean i can just reposte it and be more clear in what i want but then the already existing answers would be gone and that would be a waste.

Comment: @AxelLP there's some discussion on the site around "list questions" which tend to cause some problems. I think the best entry-point is [this meta.rpgse post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6442/23970). The short of it is that a question that generates a bunch of list-item answers (like this one already has) interacts poorly with the voting model. Personally, I can't exactly put my finger on what in your original question *caused* this to emerge, but that's what close-voters seem to be responding to. (Also, even if the post is closed, the existing answers live on and aren't wasted.)

Comment: @nitsua60 So if i get this right its not allowed to ask for several ideas how to handle things in dnd because this voting mechanism doesnt work quite well here? All im doing is to ask for ideas on how to make my spell effects work more reliable because im sure there are many ways to do so and people seem to know ways so they just drop them here and good answers get upvotes. I dont see any problem here im sorry if im misstaken.

Comment: @AxelLP "Idea generation" questions generally fair poorly on this site. The main problem is that this is so broad it is difficult to make a solid supported answer. Sure we can list things at you that help spellcasting but it would be better if you narrow the scope and had a clearly defined target (i.e. Maximum save dc or best concentration save). The original question is closer to a quality question for the site. It may have still been closed because there are lots of ways to force disadvantage, but most only work on 1 ability at a time and it was unclear if you wanted these included.

Comment: @AxelLP What you are encountering here is a particular way in which an SE site is not a forum, and that is on purpose.  This model works best (otherwise, the whole voting thing doesn't work) when what is presented is a well scoped question that addresses a single problem.  I see what you are getting at; "how do I make it harder to save versus my {x kind of } spell."  If you want this reopened you need to narrow the scope of the question.  (And I completely get where you are coming from in terms of casters trying to get the most out of each spell.  Then Legendary saves happen and it fails.

Comment: By the way "mageclass" isn't a class in D&D 5e.  Pick a class and ask how to do it for that class.

Answer (score 9):

## The Sorcerer Metamagic: Heightened Spell

> When you Cast a Spell that forces a creature to make a saving throw to resist its Effects, you can spend 3 sorcery points to give one target of the spell disadvantage on its first saving throw made against the spell.

That would be the only such feature coming to my mind right now. Of course since it is a metamagic, it is difficult to use as an orientation for creating another class, but at least we can see that it costs a lot of sorcery points just to give a single target disadvantage on a single saving throw. That means the designers valued this effect extremely highly and you should be careful not to give it out too freely when building a class around it.

Comment: Ty thats helpfull, but i didnt mean to homebrew a class or something ;)

Comment: actualy this effect is pretty much what i had in mind! But restricting me to a class kinda sucks :/. Though the best class for my char would may be Wizard.

Comment: Just multi class 3 sorc 17 wizard.  Then you still get all the spell slots and 9th level wizard spells and metamagic.

Comment: @SamLacrumb As far as i know sorcery points increase with the SORCERER lvl and if i get lvl 3 SORCERER and lvl 17 wizard i would only have 3 sorcery points meaning i can use this feature only once per short or long rest idk.

Comment: No you can use a bonus action to trade a spell slots for more.   It's worked out well for me so far.

Answer (score 7):

## Magical Ambush - Rogue Arcane Trickster

This is a class feature that you gain at Level 9 that imposes disadvantage on spells you cast when hidden from your target.

Comment: Not realy helpfull because i wanted it for a spellcaster and i would not realy call a rouge a spellcaster but thanks anyway!

Comment: @AxelLP An arcane trickster is definitely a spellcaster, and they access the wizard spell list you were looking for.

Comment: I never said that im looking for the wizard spell list even though many cc spells are in the 
wizard list. Also he might be a spellcaster but he still is a rogue and only has up to 4th lvl spell slots and overall does not have much spellslots which would be a problem if i want to focus on cc. Cant blame anyone exept me though because i stated that i wanted to play a spellcaster and didnt say i want a mage so im sorry.

Answer (score 0):

### Unearthed Arcana: the Mind Sliver cantrip

The Mind Sliver cantrip from the most recent [Psionics Unearthed Arcana article](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_PsionicOptions.pdf) is a damaging cantrip that gives the target a 1d4 penalty on the next save it makes before the end of your next turn if it fails its save against the cantrip.

This does involve another spell and require the target to fail a saving throw, but as it's a cantrip, you won't be using up your limited numbers of spell slots on it. It's not disadvantage, but as another mechanic that increases the likelihood of a failed save, it seems relevant enough to mention.

It's available to Sorcerers, Warlocks and Wizards; if you're not playing one of those, the usual cantrip access routes like being a High Elf or taking the Magic Initiate feat would also work.

As noted in the article, this is playtest content, so it's possible your DM won't allow it.

Comment: That's not disadvantage, it's a d4. Same effect as *bane* which is an official option.

Comment: I've edited to make a little clearer why I think this is more relevant than Bane. Still possible it won't meet the OP's requirements, but I think there's a significant enough difference between a resource-free option and a 1st level spell for it to be worth mentioning.

Comment: The bane example was just to show there are other d4 options, but neither are the disadvantage that OP requested.